# Error assigning return value of a char-pointer-function to an array of char variable in Keil for micro 8051

Tags: c, arrays, lvalue, 8051, keil

I am currently working on a project of 128 bit addition using 8 bit 8051 using Keil. Here is my main program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Li.h"
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    unsigned char a[17],b[17],p[17],tes[17],c[17];
    char temp,i;
    //main function starts
    //unsigned char *c = (char*) malloc(17);
    memset(c,0,17);
    temp=0;
    i=2;
    memset(a,0,17);
    memset(b,0,17);
    memset(p,0,16);

    a[0]=0xB2;
    a[1]=0x21;

    b[0]=0x6A;
    b[1]=0x6;

    p[0]=0xF0;
    p[1]=0x1F;

    for(i=1;i>=1;i--)
    {
        if ((b[i] & 128) == 128)
        {
            c = add(c,a);
            c = add(c,c);
            c = mod(c,p);
            c[3] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The called function add :

```
 #include <REG51.H>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>                              
 #include "Li.h"
 #include <string.h>

 unsigned char* add (unsigned char a[17],unsigned char b[17])
 {
    //main function starts
    unsigned char c[17];
    //unsigned char *c = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*17);
    char i,temp;
    //memset(c,(int)0,17*sizeof(unsigned char));        
    memset(c,0,17);
    i=0;
    temp = 0;
    for(i=0; i <17 ; i++)
    {
        c[i]=a[i]+b[i]+temp;
        temp = 0;
        if ((c[i] < a[i]) || (c[i] < b[i])) 
        {   
            temp = 1;
            //temp = temp >> 4;
        }
    }
    return c;   
}
```

The error occurs when I try to assign c = add(c,a) in the main program, the error : **left side of asn-op not an lvalue**. I have create the same size array for "c=add(c,a)", which is c[17] and a[17] in the main program and in the called function.

What's the problem with "left side of asn-op not an lvalue" ?
Thanks guys :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am having trouble assigning a char string to a char array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077207/i-am-having-trouble-assigning-a-char-string-to-a-char-array) - you simply cannot assign to arrays in C.

Comment: Please learn to format your code! This does not look good.

Comment: This line: for(i=1;i>=1;i--) will always only cause one execution of the loop,  so why incorporate it?

Comment: the line: if ((b[i] & 128) == 128) is only executed once. (see prior comment) and the value of 'i' will be 1 so the line is b[1] and the value of b[1] is 0x06.  So the high order bit (0x80 I.E. 128) will always be equal 0, so the following code will never execute.

Comment: the code to add the successive characters of the array starts on the wrong end of the array and fails to allow for overflow, so needs some re-design.  This link may be helpful.  http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/djimenez/utsa/cs3343/lecture20.html

Answer (score 0):

```
I suggest you modify the add() function and the lines that invoke the add() function
to something similar to:
#define MAX_BYTES 16
char    a[MAX_BYTES+1];
// plus other data definitions, etc

bool addStatus = true; // true means successful add of two 64 bit values

// add 64 bit a array and 64 bit b array and put the result in 64 bit c array
addStatus = add64(c,a,b);
// plus other 64 bit add operations

bool add64( char *destination, char *source1, char *source2 )
{
    bool resultStatus = true; // indicate add successful


    // assuming all arrays are MAX_LOOP chars long
    int carry = 0;     // tracks byte addition overflow
    int loopCount = 0; // tracks number of loops performed
    char dest[16] = 0; // work area

    for( loopCount=0; loopCount < MAX_LOOPS; loopCount++ )
    {
        // your code to add 2 bytes + carry and extract new carry value
    } // end for( each byte in array )

    memcpy( destination, dest, sizeof(dest) ); // set caller's result array 

    return( (carry)? false : true ); // if carry not 0, overflow occurred
} // end function: add64()
```